# Firestore query rules with sub collections

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question regarding firestore rules.

I have a collection that holds documents... and these documents also have sub- collections.... and these documents also have subcollections.

e.g.

```
"Collection" -> "Document" -> "Sub-collection-1"  -> "Document1" -> "Sub-collection-2" -> "Document2"
              
(i have changed the names to make it simpler to understand)
```

I have a 2 timestamps stored in the "Document" that are used to control when the user is able to read the document... e.g. it must be after the 'startTimestamp' but before the 'endTimestamp'.

My rules for this are as follows.

```
        allow read: if request.auth.uid != null
                  && int(resource.data.startReadTimestamp) < request.time.toMillis()
                  && int(resource.data.endReadTimestamp) > request.time.toMillis()
```

My question is that if the user tries to read a sub-collection document, e.g. "Document1" or "Document2" and the time they request is invalid based on the timestamps in "Document" will this automatically reject because of the parent collection rule?

If not, I have seen that you can use the functions combined with get to access other documents but it seems wasteful as this will be charging me reads.

e.g. doing this

```
  function getTopLevelDocData() {
            return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Collection/$(documentWildcard)).data
        }
```

The only other method I can think of is writing the timestamps to each document in the sub collection... but this could be hard to keep track of.

Any help is appreciated :)

--- UPDATE

I just tried it and it does allow reads to "Document1" If i dont call the function that checks the "Document" timestamps in the "Document1" rules... Just to clarify will reading "Document1" or "Document2" be only 1 extra read as it will have to check the "Document" timestamps?

--- SECOND UPDATE

Imagine "Document" in the above example actually has the doc name "2020-08-29".

If I try to read "Document1" or "Document2" is there a firestore rule that will not incur any document reads but will still block reads where the request timestamp (after transformation) does not match the parent "Document" name, e.g. "2020-08-29"

for Example, would something like this work?

```
match /collection/{document}{
   match /Sub-collection-1/{document1}{

      function transfomRequestTimestampToDate(){
           return request.time.year() + "-" + request.time.month() + request.time.day();
      }

      allow read  if request.auth.uid != null && transfomRequestTimestampToDate() == {document}
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just tried it and it does allow reads If i dont call the function...

You don't show to which collection(s) you apply the `read` security rules shown in your question, but note that `resource.data` points to the [`resource`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource?authuser=0) you are trying to read, therefore if you don't have the corresponding fields in the subcollections docs, it will not work as such for these docs.

> Will reading "Document1" or "Document2" be only 1 extra read as it
> will have to check the "Document" timestamps?

Yes, it will cont for one document read each time the security rule is evaluated.

---

#### UPDATE following your second update

Yes, by using the wildcard syntax, you can use the document ID of the parent to write the rules for the children, like, for example, as follows:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Collection/{parentDocId} {
      allow read: if parentDocId == '2020-08-29';

        match /Subcollection1/{SubcollectionDoc} {
           allow read: if parentDocId == '2020-08-29';
        }
    }
  }
}
```

and if you want to make this dynamic, you could do as follows:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /a/{a} {
      allow read: if a == string(request.time.year()) + "-" + string(request.time.month()) + "-" +  string(request.time.day());

        match /b/{b} {
                 allow read: if a == string(request.time.year()) + "-" + string(request.time.month()) + "-" +  string(request.time.day());

        }
    }
  }
}
```

However, note that `string(request.time.day())` and `string(request.time.month())` will return a string of one character for months before October, e.g. 8 for August or days before 10. It's up to you to deal with that, either by using YYYY-M-D or by fine tuning the security rule.

Comment: is there anyway I can turn the request.time into a YYYY-MM-DD string in the firestore rules?

Comment: You should be able to use the [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Timestamp) methods

Comment: Great. Assuming "Document" is actually a YYYY-MM-DD string could I avoid the extra read by just using the timestamp methods and  somehow using $(documentWildcard) to get the doc name... or will this still be a read?

Comment: To be able to answer this last question, you would need to give precise examples by updating your question (exact security rules, including the paths, fields names and values, etc... plus exact queries). Now, generally speaking, if the two `ReadTimestamp` fields are in the parent doc, you will need to read this doc, as I don't think there is a workaround for that...

Comment: Note that it would not be a bad practice to denormalize your data and have the same `ReadTimestamp` fields/values in the children docs (as you mention at the bottom of your question), however this may incur some extra writes (e.g. if you use a Cloud Function to update the children docs). It's up to you to calculate what is the best approach, depending on your exact use case.

Comment: Ive updated my question again... I've tried to word it best i can but it still may sound confusing

Comment: See the update to my answer. Don't forget to check that you are not creating new documents at a very high rate, since, by using YYYY-MM-DD as doc ID you may be allocating you own monotonically increasing IDs, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices?authuser=0#high_read_write_and_delete_rates_to_a_narrow_document_range

Comment: Updated again with example rules, although i dont think the syntax with is correct on the == {document} part

Comment: Oh i think you misunderstood. I will have multiple documents named based on dates and users should only be able to read the current Date document e.g. todays utc date means they should only be able to read a document named 2020-08-29... so the rules would need to be dynamic based on the time and the name of the parent doc.

Comment: Yes, I understood, but I was just showing an example with static values. I've updated the answer with one possible solution.

Comment: It will count one read for the b document (if the user is allowed to read the doc, of course), but no extra read generated by the security rules.

Comment: Thats awesome! Thanks so much for your help  :) .... I think i can completely remove my start/end timestamps and just use this method. Ill try to find a method to append the 0 for 1-9 Days as you suggested. Thanks again!